# Get product weight from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The code below is used to get data on a products of the category "books" in my Wordpress website using Woocommerce.

```
<?php
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 200, 'product_cat' => 'books');
       $loop = new WP_Query( $args );


    $send_array = array();
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        global $product; 

    $send_array[] = array(

        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'content' => get_the_content(),
        'regular_price' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true),
        'sale_price'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true),
        'weight' => woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'weight', 'names')

    );

     endwhile; 

     wp_reset_query(); 
        ob_clean();
        echo json_encode($send_array);
        exit();

    ?>
```

This works fine and returns the data correctly except for the `weight` attribute.

This is a custom attribute set in my website using Woocommerce. In my database the weight attribute shows up in the `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` table. This table has the fields `attribute_id`, `attribute_name`, `attribute_label` etc.

The code I used above to get the `weight` value of the product doesn't work.

I also tried `'weight' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_weight', true)`, but it shows up as an empty string (weight:"") even though that product has a Weight value on the website.

How do I get the weight for each product and add it to the array to the key `weight` as I have attempted above.

Have been doing some research and this seemed to be the item to work. What am I doing wrong?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in getting the weight of a particular product.

```
$item_weight=wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'pa_weight', array("fields" => "names"));

$send_array[] = array(

    'id' => get_the_ID(),
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'content' => get_the_content(),
    'regular_price' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true),
    'sale_price'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true),
    'weight' => $item_weight[0]

);
```

This looked at a defined post in the loop to return the attribute values for `pa_weight`.

Answer (score 17):

```
global $product;    
$product->get_weight();
```

Comment: Thanks, this method made my day more simpler

Comment: Answers the question - makes this a high quality answer

Answer (score 2):

The Woo Commerce function 'woocommerce_get_product_terms' returns an array. I am not intimately familiar with the results of that function from Woo Commerce, but assuming that it doesn't return a multi-dimensional array, you should assign the terms to a variable outside of your $send_array array and try returning the first item in the array.

```
$weight = woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'pa_weight', 'names');
```

Then you array would use the $weight variable like so:

```
$send_array[] = array(

    'id' => get_the_ID(),
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'content' => get_the_content(),
    'regular_price' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true),
    'sale_price'=> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true),
    'weight' => $weight[0]

);
```

If that doesn't work, you should do a var_dump($weight) of the variable to see how Woo Commerce returns the result of the function. From that output you should be able determine the proper index to use to get the result you are after.

Comment: I tried this, but then the value for the key `weight` showed up as "null", and when I use the `var_dump($weight)`, the page shows up blank. Nothing returned.

Comment: You have to preface your attribute keys with 'pa_' so weight should be 'pa_weight'. I set up an attribute for weight to test it and that returns an array of weights for me.

Comment: You mean add the preface "pa_" in the Wordpress back end dashboard? Or do I just have to change to "pa_weight" in the code above, ie, `$weight = woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'pa_weight', 'names');`

Comment: No. This: `woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'weight', 'names')` becomes this: `woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'pa_weight', 'names')`. Woo Commerce prefaces product attributes with 'pa_' when they are saved to the db. I have edited my answer above with the addition.

Comment: Tried that but still the same result. Value shows up as null

Comment: You are adding the weights as a 'Attributes' area in the 'Product Data' section, aren't you? This: `woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'pa_weight', 'names')` should give you an array of weights, and this: `woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->id, 'pa_weight', 'all')` should give you an array of objects with all the attribute's, er, attributes.

Comment: Yes, I add the weight for a product under the Product data section. I set a new attribute under the Product>Attributes tab. In the database table `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies`, the `attribute name` is "weight" and the `attribute label` is "Product Weight"

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out also.

```
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
$x = 0;
foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
    $_product2 = $values['data'];

    $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );

    echo $getProductDetail->get_image(); // accepts 2 arguments ( size,      attr )

    $weight = $getProductDetail->product_attributes;
    echo 'Weight: '.$weight["weight"]["value"].'<br>';
}
```